# Django admin crosspage action

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a django admin panel for my model, it contains a lot of records so I have pagination.

**The question is following**: Is it possible to make 'selection' working cross-page? Because right now if I select some entries on the first page and switch to the second, selection from first disappears which actually makes sense :).

**For now I have two solutions**:

1) Display all entries on one page - I don't like it because this one page will be huge and probably because of that really slow.

2) Override template to put selected entries into some intermediate storage - I don't like this one, because it sounds like a lot of code.

I hope that there is some way to do it faster, some special django attribute that makes this kind of magic, otherwise I guess I will stick with **second** option.

Comment: So you want the action to affect **all** instances of a Model?

Comment: @aumo, Not all of them, but just selected once.

Comment: But how do you select rows that are not displayed on the page?

Comment: That's my question :)

Comment: gMail does this when you scroll through multiple pages and have emails selected on various pages. Although it's not exactly intuative from the user perspective as there's no total/count of the item's that are selected. Short answer: 2) You're gonna need to write some code for this.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you want the selection to be persistent so you only run the action once. Maybe you should rephrase your question, "selection" seems more pertinent than "action" here.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, updated.

Comment: BTW, I don't see a simple solution to this problem. Maybe an alternative list page where you load all objects and only display attributes belonging to them (so no extra DB queries) made specially for selection.